# Hadoop no space error

Tags: hadoop

When I submit a `Hadoop` jar on `hdfs`, I'm facing

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException : No space left on
>   device

Any one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

usually an issue with the limit of open files or processes on the linux box. Try ulimit -a to view limits. you are interested in

open files                      (-n) 1024
max user processes              (-u) 102400

to set the open files limit
ulimit -n xxxx

to set the max processes limit
ulimit -u xxxx